# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of null angular form not seeing the nested FormBuilder group

Tags: angular, typescript

The nested form group is not readable for html file!

```
this.addSaleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      storeId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      clientId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      saleDateTime: ['', [Validators.required]],
      amountPaid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
      invoice: this.formBuilder.group({
        discount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)]],
        description: ['', [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(250)]],
        serial: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
        signture: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      })
    });
```

html of the component couldn't read **invoice** as a formGroupName although that the rest of for controls is readable without problem!

```html
<div [formGroupName]="invoice">
      <!-- Row of Serial & Signture & DateTime -->
      <div class="form-row">
        <!-- Serial Form Group -->
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <input
            type="number"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                addSaleForm.get('serial').errors &&
                addSaleForm.get('serial').touched
            }"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="serial"
            placeholder="Serial"
          />
          <div
            class="invalid-feedback"
            *ngIf="
              addSaleForm.get('serial').hasError('required') &&
              addSaleForm.get('serial').touched
            "
          >
            Invoice Serial is required
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> html of the component couldn't read invoice as a formGroupName
>   although that the rest of for controls is readable without problem!

The problem is that you're using property binding for `formGroupName` (`[formGroupName]`) where you should use simply `formGroupName`.

---

To access the nested control `serial` you can do the following:

```
[ngClass]="{
  'is-invalid':
    addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial').errors &&
    addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial').touched
}"
```

```
*ngIf="
  addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial').hasError('required') &&
  addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial').touched
"

... or even better IMHO:

*ngIf="
  addSaleForm.hasError('required', 'invoice.serial') &&
  addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial').touched
"
```

---

Full template (with a little refactor -- using `[class]` binding and the "as" syntax to create a reference for the serial `form control`):

```
<div formGroupName="invoice">
  <!-- Row of Serial & Signture & DateTime -->
  <div class="form-row">
    <!-- Serial Form Group -->
    <div class="col mb-3" *ngIf="addSaleForm.get('invoice.serial') as serialFormControl">
      <input
        type="number"
        [class.invalid]="serialFormControl.errors && serialFormControl.touched"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="serial"
        placeholder="Serial"
      />
      <div
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="serialFormControl.hasError('required') && serialFormControl.touched"
      >
        Invoice Serial is required
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```